# Data at the root level is invalid when calling ReadXml on a Dataset

Tags: c#, gridview

I have writtten the following code .....

as am pushing data from xml files

I am getting error as

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
```

---

I have writtten the following code .....

as am pushing data from xml files

I am getting error as

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kkkkkk
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ds = new DataSet();
            dv = new DataView();
        }

        public DataSet ds
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }

        public DataView dv
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "C:/Users/EXLVIS/Desktop/t.xml";
             ds.ReadXml(path);       
              dv.Table = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;


        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "Server like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
             dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        }
    }
}
```

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <NewDataSet>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server1</Server> 
  <Database>Database1</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server2</Server> 
  <Database>Database2</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server3</Server> 
  <Database>Database3</Database> 
  </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
```

Comment: The problem is not in your code it probably is in your XML. Can you share a **small** example of what your xml look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <NewDataSet>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server1</Server> 
  <Database>Database1</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server2</Server> 
  <Database>Database2</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server3</Server> 
  <Database>Database3</Database> 
  </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>

Comment: You see the gray *edit* at the left under your question? You can click that to edit your question and add that xml snippet to your question (make sure you mark it as code).

Answer (score 0):

Given the error: `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.`

And if the XML is truly as you've posted, then the error is saying the "-" characters are invalid since they are outside the XML structure.

In other words, this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <NewDataSet>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server1</Server> 
  <Database>Database1</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server2</Server> 
  <Database>Database2</Database> 
  </Table1>
- <Table1>
  <Server>Server3</Server> 
  <Database>Database3</Database> 
  </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
```

Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
  <Server>Server1</Server> 
  <Database>Database1</Database> 
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
  <Server>Server2</Server> 
  <Database>Database2</Database> 
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
  <Server>Server3</Server> 
  <Database>Database3</Database> 
  </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
```